# Vulnerabilities in SHA-1

Tags: hash, sha-1

Are there any known vulnerabilities in SHA-1 that can be exploited? Certain patterns that it shows? I recently performed a frequency analysis using 20,000 common words, and found nothing exploitable. What others techniques can I use to assert the security of SHA-1?

Comment: Space is a bit short here to repeat all the papers written about SHA-1. Your frequency analysis was bound to fail, but that tells absolutely nothing about the security or insecurity of SHA-1.